# Custom Marker-Symbol in GeoJSON marker (MAPBOX)

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson

I have the problem described here: [Mapbox Marker Symbol with Three Digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507910/mapbox-marker-symbol-with-three-digits)

I am trying to visualize **marker with three or more digits** in it.

So far I found this solution:

JavaScript:

```
L.NumberedDivIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
    number: ''
    },
    createIcon: function () {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var numdiv = document.createElement('div');
        numdiv.setAttribute ( "class", "number" );
        numdiv.innerHTML = this.options['number'] || '';
        div.appendChild ( numdiv );
        this._setIconStyles(div, 'icon');
        return div;
    }
});

var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(40, -78), {
    icon:   new L.NumberedDivIcon({number: '123'})
});
marker.addTo(map);
```

CSS:

```
.leaflet-marker-icon .number{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

That way I am able to create a marker like this:

[image: marker with leaflet]

**I want to use GeoJSON format for creating a three-digit marker.** For example:

```
L.mapbox.markerLayer({
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [-99, 36.9]
    },
    properties: {
        title: 'A Single Marker',
        description: 'Just one of me',
        // one can customize markers by adding simplestyle properties
        // http://mapbox.com/developers/simplestyle/
        'marker-size': 'large',
        'marker-color': '#775556',
        'marker-symbol': '11'
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Please note that '**marker-symbol**': 'X' supports numbers with maximum two digits.

How can I achieve this?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4NqS6/23/)

Comment: Do you want the marker to appear like the `marker-symbol` or a circle like you have created?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It is better to be like marker-symbol.